# How to put conditional output like arthmemetic , value o/p should be greater than = 30k and less that = 30 k

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

[image]enter image description heresourcetype=xxxxx "connection from 17.129.249.164" OR "connection from 17.208.230.209" OR "connection from 10.41.84.33" OR "connection from 10.41.158.214" OR "connection from 10.41.88.162" OR "connection from 10.41.157.80" OR "connection from 10.41.88.198" OR "connection from 17.208.225.42" OR "connection from 10.41.92.81" OR "connection from 10.41.92.237" | rex field=_raw "connection from (?\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+):"| bin span=1d _time |chart max(value)  count by _time FROM_IP limit=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stats` command instead of `chart`. That will give you a count column

`sourcetype=xxxxx "connection from 17.129.249.164" OR "connection from 17.208.230.209" OR "connection from 10.41.84.33" OR "connection from 10.41.158.214" OR "connection from 10.41.88.162" OR "connection from 10.41.157.80" OR "connection from 10.41.88.198" OR "connection from 17.208.225.42" OR "connection from 10.41.92.81" OR "connection from 10.41.92.237" | rex field=_raw "connection from (?\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+):"| bin span=1d _time | stats count by _time FROM_IP | where count > 30000 AND count < 30000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where` or `search` to filter the data to what you need.

`sourcetype=xxxxx "connection from 17.129.249.164" OR "connection from 17.208.230.209" OR "connection from 10.41.84.33" OR "connection from 10.41.158.214" OR "connection from 10.41.88.162" OR "connection from 10.41.157.80" OR "connection from 10.41.88.198" OR "connection from 17.208.225.42" OR "connection from 10.41.92.81" OR "connection from 10.41.92.237" | rex field=_raw "connection from (?\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+):"| bin span=1d _time |chart count by _time FROM_IP limit=0 | where count > 30000 AND count < 30000`

Comment: Problem here is the output it gives is count of connection on each ip w.r.t to days .so count > 30000 is not working for no. of connection

Comment: I have attached the output pic , if I use count > .... then there is no result